# Python: Open multiple images in default image viewer

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL to open a single image in the default image viewer:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('example.jpg')
img.show()
```

Does any Python module contain a function enabling **opening multiple images** in the current system's default image viewer? For instance when on OS X, Preview.app should open with the list of images in the sidebar. From the command line this is no problem at all:

```
$ open my_picture_number_*
```

Use case is that users should just be able to explore a few dozen images.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `subprocess.run` to run the operating system's default image viewing app.  subprocess.run works a lot like a command line.  You just need to know what the command is for the operating system you're on.  For windows, "explorer" will do; for OS X, as you point out, it's "open."  I'm not sure what it is for Linux, maybe "eog"?

So, your code would look like this:

```
import sys
import subprocess

def openImage(path):
    imageViewerFromCommandLine = {'linux':'xdg-open',
                                  'win32':'explorer',
                                  'darwin':'open'}[sys.platform]
    subprocess.run([imageViewerFromCommandLine, path])
```

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to use @jgfoot's answer, which worked, but made my program hang after the viewer was launched. I've solved this issue by using subprocess.Popen instead, like this:

```
import sys
import subprocess

def openImage(path):
    imageViewerFromCommandLine = {'linux':'xdg-open',
                                  'win32':'explorer',
                                  'darwin':'open'}[sys.platform]
    subprocess.Popen([imageViewerFromCommandLine, path])
```